# OpenERP - ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: purchase.menu_purchase_form_action

Tags: openerp-7, purchase-order

I am new to OpenERP.  I am getting this error while installing or uninstalling a module in my openerp.

I am not able to find where it went wrong.
Here is the error log:

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 495, in button_immediate_uninstall
    return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_uninstall, context=context)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 475, in _button_immediate_function
    _, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 233, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 354, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 256, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 188, in load_module_graph
    load_data(module_name, idref, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 76, in <lambda>
    load_data = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='data')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 124, in _load_data
    tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 954, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot())
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 847, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 805, in _tag_record
    f_val = self.id_get(cr, f_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 824, in id_get
    res = self.model_id_get(cr, id_str)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 833, in model_id_get
    return model_data_obj.get_object_reference(cr, self.uid, mod, id_str)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
    r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 872, in get_object_reference
    data_id = self._get_id(cr, uid, module, xml_id)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 18, in lookup
    r = self.lookup(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 46, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(self2, cr, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 865, in _get_id
    raise ValueError('No such external ID currently defined in the system: %s.%s' % (module, xml_id))
ValueError: No such external ID currently defined in the system: purchase.menu_purchase_form_action
```

Can I have any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time Chaitanya and User3736293... Actually the issue is, in **ir_model_data** table, entry is missing for "menu_purchase_form_action" record.  I have fixed this issue by adding the record.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Purchase module, i think in your **openerp**.py file has mistake, you have to add in **openerp**.py file `'depends':['base','purchase'],` now check this it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may not add the entry for view.xml file in **openerp**.py file in purchase module